# Bootstrap 3 - Managing column wrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Needing to nest rows in Bootstrap 3.  Main requirements

1. Three large columns
2. Each column equal width
3. Columns to contain either one or two images
4. Layout structure should be maintained for all device sizes

This Codeply is where we are at right now
http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/jwSEq9JSrH

The layout is as required for desktop but goes funny on tablet down
We'd welcome any comments

Kind regards 
Mike

Comment: I've checked your code. you have given somewhere col-md and somewhere col-sm only. You need to handle all the resolution by specifying md and sm and xs

Comment: Thanks Arvaan - looking it now

Comment: If you have any trouble with code. paste your code here. we glad to help you